# Javascript array filter() with bind()

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, bind

I'm using the filter() array helper going through some objects in an array. My idea is to create a dynamic filtering function to go through the objects in the array using bind(), but the arguments in bind are being used in a different way that I expected. Here's the code:

```js
var products = [
  {name:"lettuce", type:"vegetable"},
  {name:"apple", type:"fruit"},
  {name:"carrot", type:"vegetable"},
  {name:"orange", type:"fruit"}
];

// this is the function used in filter()
function filterProducts(cat, product){
  return product.type === cat;
}

// new array
var vegetables = products.filter(filterProducts.bind(products, "vegetable"));
```

I'm assuming that the filter helper is passing each object in the array after the arguments in the bind method, so first is the products which accounts for `this` in the callback, then is the type I want to check on each object and finally the object itself.

The question is: Would you recommend doing it like this? I mean, could this be considered a good practice or would it be better to create a function to filter each type instead of doing it like this?

Comment: Why do you want to use the bind function exactly?

Comment: this is kinda a matter of opinion...

Comment: why binding `products`? it is already there for `filter` callback function as third argument.

Comment: If the argument for self reference isn't being used, for clarity it's better to set it to null

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisBeauchamp The idea is use just one function to filter the array. In real life the objects in the array have several keys. But using filter(myFunc) just passes the object to the function and not the key I want to check for.

Comment: First argument of `bind` function is `thisArg` to rebind `this` operator, you want to do : `products.filter(filterProducts.bind(null, products, "vegetable"));`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider using a factory function instead:

```js
var products = [
  {name:"lettuce", type:"vegetable"},
  {name:"apple", type:"fruit"},
  {name:"carrot", type:"vegetable"},
  {name:"orange", type:"fruit"}
];

function filterProducts(category) {
  // this is the function used in filter()
  return function filter(product) {
    return product.type === category;
  };
}

// new array
var vegetables = products.filter(filterProducts("vegetable"));

console.log(vegetables);
```

I would recommend this pattern over using `bind`, as it's a little easier to follow, at least in my opinion.

#### Clarification

If you intend to use `filterProducts` solely as a factory for `Array#filter()`, then congratulations, you've finished reading this answer. If you're complaining that the following is "icky":

```
// product to be validated
var product = {name:"lettuce", type:"vegetable"};

// validate that product is a vegetable
if (filterProduct('vegetable')(product)) {
  // code
}
```

Then keep reading.

---

Factory functions are good for defining a class of functions that differ by one or two key variables. In this case the key variable is `category`. If you want a one-off function that looks nice in a single line of code, you're gonna be hard-pressed to find one unless you're a `lodash` aficionado or something... but for this scenario, consider this instead of the above "icky" block of code:

```
// product to be validated
var product = {name:"lettuce", type:"vegetable"};
// vegetable validator
var isVegetable = filterProduct('vegetable');

// validate that product is a vegetable
if (isVegetable(product)) {
  // code
}
```

Sure, `bind` can be good in some situations, and I'm definitely not suggesting you avoid it at all costs, but you should first ask yourself whether it's really necessary or clean to use it before resorting to it.

Comment: I would go with this approach as well... Just to mention that _"Inner function remembers the environment in which it is created!"_

Comment: This is a pretty solid answer.  I always forget i can just create functions out of thin air.

Comment: Same as above, filterProduct loses all value as a stand alone function, You will never be able to just call filterProducts('orange', someObj ). With regular binding, filterProducts can be used as both a regular function and inside the filter. As this is a question about whats best practice this approach is also worse then simply binding

Comment: @lonewarrior556 your argument makes no sense. `filterProducts` in the original question can't be used as a standalone function either, since `cat` would map to `product` and `product` would map to `index`. Whether you choose to `bind` or use a generator function, `filterProducts` was never intended to be used as both a wrapper and a standalone function. In addition, this question is about best practices, so telling the asker to use `bind` when there's a more commonly used alternative that's also cleaner, is not the best answer you can give.

Comment: This may be a simplified version of what @Rodrigo might actually want. But even if this is it,. Somewhere later on in his code he may want to check if the current product is type  "vegtable". He can then reuse it in an if statement. ie `if( filterProducts(prod, 'vegtable) )`  Maybe unlikely,  but putting it in a constructor give you nothing other than avoiding bind and losing this option.

Comment: @lonewarrior556 if that's what you want, it's easy: `if (filterProducts('vegetable')(product)) {...` so your argument still doesn't make sense.

Comment: `filterProducts('vegetable')(product)` vs `filterProducts(prod, 'vegtable')` if the former is best practice then I have to rewrite a lot of code.

Comment: bind is not bad. It is not considered good practice to avoid it by using elaborate ways.

Comment: @lonewarrior556 You can either implement `filterProducts` with one signature or the other. If you're going to argue that "in Y scenario this isn't the best option" when the question is clearly only about X scenario, then you could waste time and implement a convoluted polymorphic function that accepts both signatures, but that's obviously not clean or readable code. This question is about generating an array filter, not validating a single object. Stop trying to make baseless arguments about completely irrelevant scenarios.

Comment: Holy molly how readable, maintainable, easy to understand... Bind is dead now! Thank you so much man!

Answer (score 2):

This is really a matter of opinion. 
Some people use bind more than others. With es6 arrow notation, writing the function in the callback will prob be preferred over binding.

Only note I would make is that for clarity, when using bind,

```
var sayName = function(name){
  console.log(name)
}
var sayTony = sayName.bind(null,'Tony')
```

It's best practice to put `null` in as the first argument if it's not being used inside the function.

If you really value readability you can be more explicit and declare another function.

```
function filterProducts(cat, product){
  return product.type === cat;
}
var filterVegtables = filterProducts.bind(null, 'vegtable');
```

then you can do

```
var vegetables = products.filter(filterVegtables);
```

Comment: Yep, noticed that from your comment. I'll edit the code to avoid that. Thanks!!

Comment: Should be the hightest score answer, don't understand why the first answer is not with bind when the OP ask for bind. 

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in something like this ?

```
var products = [
  {name:"lettuce", type:"vegetable"},
  {name:"apple", type:"fruit"},
  {name:"carrot", type:"vegetable"},
  {name:"orange", type:"fruit"}
];

// this is the function used in filter()
function filterProducts(cat){
  return this.type === cat[0];
}
// new array
var veggies = products.filter(function(value){

  return filterProducts.bind(value, ['vegetable'])();
});
console.log(veggies);
```

I still used the bind, but it does become more of a two liner.  Now our value is this (so each element in the array), and our param (cat) is an array, which is why I grab [0] of it.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrBaLB

Comment: but this can be replaced with `products.filter(function(value){ return value.type === 'vegetable';}); ` so im not really seeing the value here.

Comment: Are you bashing your own answer?

Comment: The answer is works, its not terrible.  He wanted it with bind and filter so I did that.  I think having bind is a bit pointless with the little complexity in the filter func.

Answer (score 0):

The Array.filter() method isn't that magic, it will only iterate over the array and call the function for each entry.
Don't get me wrong- I'm a fan of elegant solutions, but what you're trying to do is nosense.
What you schuld do is (this code is untested and for explanation);

```
function filterCondition(obj, arg1, arg2, arg3,.. ) {
  //TODO: define your individual filter logic
}

var filter = function(products, arg1, arg2, arg3,.. ) {
  var filtered = [];
  for (var i= 0, l = products.length; i < l; i++) {
    var product = products[i];
    if (filterCondition(product, arg1, arg2, arg3,.. ))
      filtered.push(product);
  return filtered;
}
```

Using bind() means, executing the function in a scope that was defined during bind.. 1st argument.
So if you need to bind this function, you can use it:

```
filter.bind(products, arg1, arg2, arg3,..);
```

But this means, that the filter function gets executed in the scope of the products-Array.
So you have to modify the parameters:

```
var filter = function(arg1, arg2, arg3,.. ) {
  var filtered = [];
  for (var i= 0, l = this.length; i < l, i++) {
    var product = this[i];
    if (filterCondition(product, arg1, arg2, arg3,.. ))
      filtered.push(product);
  return filtered;
}
```

btw: Jean-François used this on the array-entry.. that's not wrong, just looks a little bit confusing

Answer (score -1):

I believe this would give the result you want:

```
var products = [
  {name:"lettuce", type:"vegetable"},
  {name:"apple", type:"fruit"},
  {name:"carrot", type:"vegetable"},
  {name:"orange", type:"fruit"}
];

// this is the function used in filter()
function filterProducts(product) {
  return product.type === this.toString();
}

// new array
var vegetables = products.filter(filterProducts, "vegetable");
```

but I am not using the bind function.

Comment: Quiet poor and unnecessary use of `this`

Comment: @Rayon Can you explain your comment please?

Comment: this, almost always is used for references to objects, making it a string does not really follow the typically pattern of the language.

Comment: @Rayon Maybe you are right, I don't know. If you would explain what is your reasoning, it could shed some light.

Comment: @JDE How would you pass the filter type then? You could make it a global variable, but that would not be cleaner.

Comment: you are locking yourself into using bind(or call, apply) whenever you use the filterProduct function in the rest of your code.

Comment: @lonewarrior556 Using bind or call, apply... What do you mean?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisBeauchamp you would have to do something like bind or write out a function in filter, `.filter(function(el){return filterProducts(el, "vegetable");})`. filterproducts can be `filterProducts(product, cat){product.type === cat;}` My answer up above showed how you could use bind and this on the object instead of the string. but my comment on the answer up above is still the same, there is little added value in creating something for the filter unless the filter is complex.  Which if its that complex you could just have an object hold all the product with a custom filter function

Comment: filterProduct loses all value as a stand alone function, You will never be able to call filterProducts('orange', someObj ) you will have to do filterProducts.call('orange',someOBJ). With regular binding, filterproducts can be used as a regular function and inside the filter. As this is a question about whats best practice this approach is worse then binding